# How do I listen to the actions contained in a transaction to my smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions

For example, if Alice sends a `transfer` from the `eosio.token` contract to my smart contract, how do I listen to see if she has actually sent me a `transfer` from the `eosio.token` contract and get the data from the action?

Answer (score 1):

Ah nevermind.
There is an example in the tic-tac-toe contract https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/tic_tac_toe/tic_tac_toe.cpp

You can use the `apply` method to listen to an incoming action but you must declare `extern "C"` beforehand.

```
//tic-tac-toe contract example    
extern "C" {
  void apply( uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action ) {
    //logic goes in here
  }
}
```

Comment: If you rephrase this as an actual answer with full explanation, it would probably be worthy of an upvote.

Comment: Where? I don't see that contract resolving your question.